# Reproducción de audio Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, audio

Estoy trabajando con Ionic 6 y angular (Capacitor).

Intento reproducir un audio que esta en una url pública (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav), esto funciona bien cuando realizo la prueba en mi navegador, pero cuando lo pruebo en un dispositivo móvil real, no me funciona aparece como si le hubiera puesto un disable.

Realice una prueba que consistió en modificar la dirección por (../../assets/media/Audio1.mp3) y de esta forma si me funciona en el dispositivo móvil.

Como puedo lograr reproducir mi archivo de la url publica (http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav) en la app Android

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
  <audio controls>
     <source src="http://138.91.126.10:1011/PLAZA%20MAY%20AUDIOGUIA.wav" type="audio/wav" />
  </audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, me hacia falta algo de configuración en la app Android, en el documento **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** agregue dos líneas, al inicio en la etiqueta  **application**  `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` y al final del documento la línea   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

imagen 1: [image: En la etiqueta aplication]

imagen 2: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la solución la tome de la dirección:https://programmerclick.com/article/7117706394/